# buttons refer to multiple markers on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

i used a script that has multiple markers on the map with info window , but i couldn't make the buttons refer to the marker , as i need when i click to the button a simple function active a specific maker and open the info window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Cover Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>



        <div class="cover-container">

        <div class="row">
            <img src="logo.png" width="550px" height="250px" class="center-block"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color:#ffffff; margin-top:-30px;">Our Banches</h1>
         </div>

        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6"><div id="googleMap" style="width:761px;height:350px;"></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

         </div>
         <br>
<center>
          <div class="row">

        <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Our Branches <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Shorouk City</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nasr City</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rehab</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
        </center>
                  <br>
                           <br>
         <br>

         <br>


         </div>


          <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

js code that i want to work on :

```
<script>
        // Define your locations: HTML content for the info window, latitude, longitude
        var locations = [
          ['<h4>Guntur Nprodax India</h4>', 16.306652, 80.436540],
          ['<h4>Vijayawada</h4>', 16.506174, 80.648015],
         ['<h4>Vizag India</h4>', 17.686816, 83.218482],
         ['<h4>Kurnool</h4>', 15.828126, 78.037279],
         ['<h4>Kadapa India</h4>', 14.467354, 78.824134],
         ['<h4>Madanapalle</h4>', 13.550000, 78.500000],
         ['<h4>Mumbai India</h4>', 19.075984, 72.877656],
         ['<h4>Ahmedabad</h4>', 23.022505, 72.571362],
         ['<h4>Chennai</h4>', 13.082680, 80.270718],
         ['<h4>Coimbatore</h4>', 11.016844, 76.955832],
         ['<h4>New Delhi</h4>', 28.644371, 77.219678]  

        ];

        // Setup the different icons and shadows
        var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

        var icons = [
          iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png'

        ]
        var iconsLength = icons.length;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.2323552,80.2649705),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          zoomControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
          }
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          maxWidth: 160
        });

        var markers = new Array();

        var iconCounter = 0;

        // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: icons[iconCounter]
          });

          markers.push(marker);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));

          iconCounter++;
          // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
          if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
            iconCounter = 0;
          }
        }

        function autoCenter() {
          //  Create a new viewpoint bound
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          //  Go through each...
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
            bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
          }
          //  Fit these bounds to the map
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        autoCenter();
      </script> 





            </div>



        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

i need this link

```
<li><a href="#">Shorouk City</a></li>
```

to refer to this marker onclick :

```
      ['<h4>Guntur Nprodax India</h4>', 16.306652, 80.436540],
```

please if u have simple function that open the marker and info window , thanks

Comment: `I couldn't make the buttons refer to the marker`.. What have you tried? PS, there is no question in your question..

Comment: Which buttons are you trying to refer to which markers?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip i need to make this link" <li><a href="#">Shorouk City</a></li> " refer to "      ['<h4>Guntur Nprodax India</h4>', 16.306652, 80.436540],
" this location and open the info window ?

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal**, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip i did that , you can check the original post , it explain all things now , thanks in advance